# Insert query string parameter into property of managed bean

Tags: jsf-2, managed-bean

I wish to pre-populate a jsf form based on the parameters in a query string. How do I go about this?

Comment: Are they GET request parameters?

Comment: as its a query string - yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`f:viewParam`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/viewParam.html) utility. Having this url:

```
/myForm.xhtml?nameField=Anthony
```

You can set the view parameter before the form itself gets rendered. Using this code in your form view:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="nameField"
        value="#{formBean.name}" />
</f:metadata>
<h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{formBean.name}" />
    <h:commandButton value="Send name" action="#{formBean.sendName}" />
</h:form>
```

The value you have specified will be set as default for the input.

**See also:**

- [What can <f:metadata>, <f:viewParam> and <f:viewAction> be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-and-fviewparam-be-used-for)

Comment: This is great thanks. However now I have a problem that the ajax for the update of these inputs is not triggered :(

Comment: I'll have a go at solving myself first

Comment: That's just the way to go. Good luck!

Comment: an update. I solved the problem mentioned in the above comment by calling the action on the page load with primefaces' remoteCommand autorun="true"

Comment: Depending on your case consider also using [`f:viewAction`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jsf22-1377252.html) if JSF 2.2 available.

Answer (score -1):

Write a bean function and call in ActionListener of that jsf page

Bean function code -

```
public void viewProperty(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    
    BindingContext bindingContext = BindingContext.getCurrent();
    
    DCDataControl dc  = bindingContext.findDataControl("AppModuleDataControl"); // Name of application module in datacontrolBinding.cpx
    
    AppModuleImpl appM = (AppModuleImpl)dc.getDataProvider();
    
    ViewObject vo = appM.findViewObject("propertyInformationNew1"); //Name of ViewObject
    String brokerUsername = MyADFUtil.getFromSessionScope("brokerUsername").toString();   
    vo.setNamedWhereClauseParam("pBrokerProp", brokerUsername); //first value is parameter name and second one is value of that parameter
    vo.executeQuery();

}
```